# VBA Set value from above cell to range below

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of files, it contains data of each and every day of a month.
I need to collect all the data to a master file and insert date for each file.
I set [the 1st day -1] in A1 cell and use the code below to set date to each day range but it is not working well. Any helps is appreciated!

```
Do While buf <> ""
Set openWB = Workbooks.Open(fold_path & "\" & buf)

With openWB.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Copy
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GA")
    .Range("B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    .Range(.Cells(Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "A"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "A")).Value = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A").Value + 1

End With

openWB.Close False
buf = Dir()　Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GA")
     With .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
       .Offset(, -1).value = .Offset(, -1).End(xlUp).value + 1
       .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
  End With
```